# SQL querying 2 tables where value not in both for a given date range

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, select

I have 2 tables in a SQL database.

The first table - *Equipment* - holds an inventory of records of machinery that is used in a company. Below are the column names for the *Equipment* table.

***id*** | ***assetnumber*** | ***make*** | ***model***

Where:

- ***id*** = the rows unique ID
- ***assetnumber*** = the machinery's unique number e.g. ABC123
- ***type*** - make of machinery
- ***model*** - model of machinery

For each piece of machinery, the operator has to complete a weekly safety check. Each submitted report is entered into a second table - *Reports*.

The *Reports* table is setup as below.

***id*** | ***userid*** | ***assetnumber*** | ***issue*** | ***weeknumber*** | ***datesubmitted***

Where:

- ***id*** = the rows unique ID
- ***userid*** = the machinery's operator ID
- ***assetnumber*** = the machinery's unique number e.g. ABC123 (matches *Equipment* tables *assetnumber*)
- ***weeknumber*** - the weeknumber the report was completed
- ***datesubmitted*** - the date/time the report was completed

I need to give admin users the ability to enter a week number e.g. 33 and then query the *Reports* table to return the list of *assetnumber* of all the machinery where a report has NOT been submitted for that piece of machinery for the queried week number. This will be used to ensure reports are done each week to meet safety standards.

I am capturing the week number from a web page to pass to a SQL query, but I dont know how to query the 2 tables to return the required data.

I am trying:

```
SELECT Equipment.assetnumber, Reports.assetnumber, Reports.weeknumber FROM Reports JOIN Reports ON Reports.assetnumber = Equipment.assetnumber WHERE Reports.weeknumber IS NULL
```

But I dont think I am on the right track.
How do I find a list of all equipment using SQL to cross reference my 2 tables?

I have also considered creating a JavaScript file that reads both tables, store them as separate Arrays then looping through the Arrays to see where the values dont match - but obviously this is way less efficient than a single SQL query.

Comment: In your code example sql you do not select anything from the Equipments table. is that right?

Comment: `FROM reports JOIN reports`? I don't believe you

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do it

First, similar to your attempt you can use a left join, which keeps all rows on the left table (Equipment) and use a "Where" to get rows with no data for the right table (Reports).

```
SELECT e.assetnumber
FROM Equipment e
  LEFT JOIN Reports r ON r.assetnumber = e.assetnumber AND r.weeknumber = 33
WHERE r.datesubmitted is NULL
```

And here's another way, even more straightforward:

```
SELECT e.assetnumber
FROM Equipment e
WHERE e.assetnumber NOT IN
  (SELECT assetnumber FROM Reports WHERE weeknumber = 33)
```